# Resaltar valor en Informe

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net, reportviewer

Trabajo con un ReportViewer que a traves de un Tablix muestra unos datos sacados de una base de datos. Utilizo Visual Studio.
El Tablix tiene el siguiente formato:

| Fecha | Goles |
| --- | --- |
| Fecha | 2 |
| Fecha | 1 |
| Fecha | 3 |
| Fecha | 1 |

Me gustaría poner la letra en verde cuando el valor de la columna goles sea 3 o superior.

Comment: Hola Brian, podrias decirme si la respuesta te resulto util y en caso de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto positivo, gracias

Comment: Buenas Japv, lo acabe haciendo de una forma parecida, pero tu forma es mas sencilla, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marca la celda del **Tablix** que quieres configurar según la condición deseada y das clic derecho sobre ella, una vez que se despliegue el menú contextual seleccionas la **opción TextBoxProperties...**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te saldrá una ventana de las propiedades de la celda(que no es más que un **TextBox** de **ReportViewer**), en esa ventana seleccionas la **propiedad Font** en el panel izquierdo y posteriormente en el panel derecho de la ventana das clic en el **botón fx** de los colores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la ventana que se te abre pegas este código:

```
=IIf(Fields!Goles.Value >= 3, "Green", "Black")
```

Este código hace uso de la **función IIF**, y **si se cumple que los goles son mayor o igual a 3 el color de fuente será verde, caso contrario se mantendrá de color negro.**

**Nota**: En mi ejemplo asumo que tu campo se llama Goles, tu quizá tengas otro nombre.